# Android setting up errors

Tags: android, google-maps

When i try to setting up to create a [google map v2 tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#get-key),android studio shows the error in the event log box like this

> Throwable: Icon cannot be found in '/icons/versions/null_32.png',
>   aClass='class icons.AndroidIcons'

this photo is when sdk verion 23

[image]

this following photo is when sdk version 22
it show error like
Failed to sync Gradle project 'Google Map'

> Error:failed to find target android-22 :
>   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk Install missing platform(s) and sync
>   project

[image]
what version shall i need to change or sth need to do?help me out please
Thanks.

Comment: It seems you are compiling vs a sdk version you do not have, or at least Android Studio does not recognise it

Comment: I think you are missing some sdk version. Click on *"Install missing platform(s) and sync project"*, it  will open the sdk manager so you can download the missing platform.